# Finding all conected subgraphs formed through edges of a directed multigraph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a directed multigraph [image: Equation] formed from a set of nodes V and a set of edges E. I'm trying to find all the possible connected subgraphs [image: Equation2] where [image: Equation3] and are not trivial, i.e. [image: equation4].

I am trying to use networkx in python to do this. Currently the only approach I have found to do this is to find every possible combination of F and then check if it is connected subgraph. This obviously quickly becomes intractable as the number of edges increases. The graphs I am working with are not huge, typically consisting of 10-30 nodes and no more that 100 edges.

From what I understand this appears to be a clique problem. I have seen that there are some implementations in networkx such as nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G), however, it appears that this returns a set of nodes and not edges. Are there any algorithms which can be used for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: `enumerate_all_cliques` is for undirected graphs. As for your comment about it not returning edges, aren't those stored in your nodes, so if you know `vf` is a connected subgraph, you have access to `f`? There's no polynomial time algorithm for something like this. For example, `enumerate_all_cliques` is exponential complexity in the worst case. If there is a trick to do it faster, it will rely on a constraint in your input. That's a big if.

Comment: The problem with forming the subgraph from nodes using networkx is that it will use all incident edges to those nodes, where in reality I am looking at the subgraphs formed from all combinations of those incident edges.

Comment: You can say something like for each node in `v`, add edge `e` to `edges` if `e.to` is in `v`.